# Windows service controller: view `sc failure` settings for a service

Tags: windows, salt-stack, servicecontroller

I would like to view the current settings of `sc failure` for a service. Is this possible?

Background:

I'm setting up state configuration for services using Saltstack. Right now, when a service is set up, a command line is run to set the failure behaviour like:

```
sc failure serviceName reset= 30 actions= restart/5000
```

I would like to be able to query the current values of the arguments passed to `sc failure`, so that Salt can verify if any changes need to be made, and log the change in values when pushing out a new configuration.

From the documentation for `sc failure` and `sc query`, I don't see anything to support this.

In the registry, at `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\myService\`, there is a key `FailureActions`. But I don't know how to read the value of this key to compare it to my desired state:

```
PS C:\Users\blaffoy> (Get-ItemProperty -path $key -name failureactions).failureactions
30
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
20
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
136
19
0
0
```

A little bit of experimentation indicates that the first number corresponds to the `reset` parameter, but beyond that I don't know how to reconcile the rest of the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sc.exe is a command-line interface to the Windows service API. [`QueryServiceConfig2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) handles several query types, which are exposed as the following commands:

- `qdescription`
- `qfailure`
- `qfailureflag`
- `qsidtype`
- `qprivs`
- `qtriggerinfo`

The command that you need is `sc [server] qfailure <service name> <bufferSize>`.